# c = a + b; How can I make c always reflect any changes made to a or b?

Tags: python, pointers

I am not sure the proper way to phrase this question. I would like to assign/bind some arithmetic (with references/pointers to other "subVariables") to a variable and have the value of the variable update if any of the contributing "subVariables" are updated.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
3
>>> a = 2
>>> c
3
```

In the ideal situation c would have a value of 4 at the end of this code sample.

--

Additional information: I am generating the arithmetic randomly and would like to be able to nest these variables (ex: d = a + c would be the same as d = a + (a + b) where d would reflect any changes that happen to a or b)

Comment: You'd have to create your custom class and overload the behavior of `+`. You can also *store the formula* in some way and evaluate it at real time

Comment: I guess what you want is a class which stores 2 numbers `a` and `b`, it also has a function `sum` to return what you need.

Comment: @Nin: It doesn't necessarily need a `sum` function or the like; if the class implements `__index__`/`__int__`, when it gets used in a scenario that requires an integer value, it can seamlessly compute the final summed value. Along with a custom `__repr__`, it can appear to be an `int` in most ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make c as a function which returns a+b value

Comment: That actually may be useful... Take for example: `c = lambda: a+b` . Then `c` would evaluate the formula at real time with current values for whichever variables might be in it. Not saying great solution, but might satisfy OP;s needs

Comment: @RafaelC the `c = lambda: a+b` does produce the desired effect and would work for `d = lambda: a + c()` also. Since I am generating the formulas randomly (and lots of them), your initial suggestion to store the formula and evaluate it as needed seems like a better solution for my scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you want isn't possible with immutable built-in types like `int`. Because `a` and `b` are bound to immutable types (`int`), even if some hypothetical class preserved references to its inputs, those inputs never change (`a` can be rebound to a new value, but `a` would no longer have anything to do with the value it was previously bound to, and the class that aliased the old value of `a` would remain unchanged; it doesn't preserve a direct tie to `a` itself).

The only way this could possibly work is if `a` and `b` were of a mutable type where the contents could be updated or reassigned, and they had an overload of `__add__`/`__radd__` that produced yet another class that stored references to instances of said mutable type and/or instances of itself (to allow the nested case). Either way, implementing such a suite of classes is *way* beyond the scope of a simple answer; I'd strongly recommend finding a different solution to your problem.

Comment: If it's absolutely necessary, [a subclass of `gmpy2.xmpz`](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advmpz.html#the-xmpz-type) (a mutable `int`-like type) that overrides `__add__`/`__radd__` might be a good base type for implementing `a` and `b`. The class that must implicitly implement `c` would still need to be written from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Simple numbers in Python are immutable references. You can't do it that directly.

You could create objects with that kind of behavior in various ways. Here's an approximation using simple function calls.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> def c():
     return a + b

>>> c()
3
>>> a = 2
>>> c()
4
```

You can avoid the `()` at the cost of a dot by using `__getattribute__`

```
>>> class CallsAttrs:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)()


>>> Q = CallsAttrs()
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> Q.c = lambda: a + b
>>> Q.c
3
>>> a = 2
>>> Q.c
4
```

And, of course, the lambdas can get the variables from `Q` too.

```
>>> Q.a = lambda: 1
>>> Q.b = lambda: 2
>>> Q.c = lambda: Q.a + Q.b
>>> Q.c
3
>>> Q.a = lambda: 40
>>> Q.c
42
```

You could also override the globals dict to work this way,

```
>>> class ThunkDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super().__getitem__(key)()


>>> exec("""
a = lambda: 1
b = lambda: 2
c = lambda: a + b
print(c)
a = lambda: -10
print(c)
""", ThunkDict())
3
-8
```

but it's not as interactive if you have to use `exec`.